# Rails 4 Route Parameters Defined by Keywords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

We're trying to set up rails routes with the parameters separated by more then just forward-slash symbols.

As an example:

```
someexample.com/SOME-ITEM-for-sale/SOME-PLACE
```

For the following path we'd like to extract SOME-ITEM and SOME-PLACE strings as parameters whilst identifying which controller to run it all against with the "-for-sale/" part.

I've been playing with variations on `:constraints => {:item => /[^\/]+/}` constructs but without any success. Am I looking in the right place? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

In the end I went with this solution:

```
get ':type/*place' => 'places#index', as: :place , :constraints => {:type => /[^\/]+-for-sale/}
```

And then recovered the full "SOME-ITEM-for-sale" sting for parsing in the controller using

```
params[:type]
```

Hope that helps someone!

Comment: if you serve Rails app through Nginx have you tried Nginx to rewrite URL in order to not making any change how Rails handles the URLs?

Comment: It seems like constraints should work in this case. Do you want to post the code for the route with constraints you tried and the results it gave you?

Comment: Thanks Val, with a bit more playing around I got this to work for me - just needed to check I was looking in the right place! - updating my question with what i used...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we went with this solution:

```
get ':type/*place' => 'places#index', as: :place , :constraints => {:type => /[^\/]+-for-sale/}
```

The router command only gets activated if the :type parameter contains "-for-sale" in the string

And then we recovered the full "SOME-ITEM-for-sale" sting for parsing in the controller using

```
params[:type]
```

Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

[`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) is what you want:

---

```
#Gemfile
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1.0'

$ rails generate friendly_id
$ rails generate scaffold item name:string slug:string:uniq
$ rake db:migrate

#app/models/item.rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   extend FriendlyId
   friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]
end
```

The above will give you a [`slug`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL#Slug) column, which `FriendlyId` will look up any requests you send to the app:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :items, path: "" do
   resources :places, path: "" #-> url.com/:item_id/:id
end
```

Although the params will still be `id` (unless you use the [`param` option](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters) of `resources`, but `FriendlyId` will override both your routes and model to use the `slug` instead:

```
<%= link_to "Item Place", items_place_path(@item, @place) %> #-> url.com/item-name-information/place-name-information
```

---

**Update**

If you wanted to have a "dynamic" routing structure, you'll be able to use the following (this requires the [`history`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/FriendlyId/History) module of `FriendlyId`):

```
#config/routes.rb
#...
get '/:item_id/:place_id', to: SlugDispatcher.new(self), as: :item #-> this has to go at the bottom 

#lib/slug_dispatcher.rb
class SlugDispatcher

  #http://blog.arkency.com/2014/01/short-urls-for-every-route-in-your-rails-app/
  ##########################################

  #Init
  def initialize(router)
    @router = router
  end

  #Env
  def call(env)
    id     = env["action_dispatch.request.path_parameters"][:item_id]
    slug   = Slug.find_by slug: id
    if slug
      strategy(slug).call(@router, env)
    else
      raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    end
  end

  ##########################################

  private

  #Strategy
  def strategy(url)
    Render.new(url)
  end

  ####################

  #Render
  class Render

    def initialize(url)
      @url = url
    end

    def call(router, env)
      item        = @url.sluggable_type.constantize.find @url.sluggable_id
      controller  = (@url.sluggable_type.downcase.pluralize + "_controller").classify.constantize 
      action      = "show"
      controller.action(action).call(env)
    end

  end

  ####################

end
```

This won't work out the box (we haven't adapted it for nested routes yet), but will provide you the ability to route to the appropriate controllers.

Comment: hmm - with someexample.com/SOME-ITEM-for-sale/SOME-PLACE how would i be able to tell the router to point at at "-for-sale" controller rather than, say, the "for-hire" controller in someexample.com/SOME-ITEM-for-hire/SOME-PLACE ?

Comment: Just use a custom constraint to look up the controller for the record & redirect to it. We've done something similar (I'll update)

Comment: thanks Rich - that sounds like the kind of thing. I'll await your update with interest...

Comment: heya Rich - In the end found a way which was a bit lighter in this case. thanks for your help. Will keep friendly_id in my back pocket for next time!